# How to differentiate wägen und wiegen for Partizip II

Tags: verb, past-participle

I would like to know how Germans differentiate between *wägen* and *wiegen*. When it comes to past participle both changes to *gewogen* (of course, the simple past is also *wog*)

Do Germans just know them by context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely uncommon to inflect *wägen* like a regular verb ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/waegen)), i.e.:

> *wägen, wägte, gewägt*

This allows for a differentiation to both verbs *wiegen,* which can only be inflected as follows:

> in the sense of *to weigh: wiegen, wog, gewogen, wöge*
>
> in the sense of *to sway* or *to rock: wiegen, wiegte, gewiegt*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be mostly context. The same thing is true for pairs like *du liest* and *du ließt* – although those two are different tenses.

It helps that *wägen* is usually used as *abwägen* or *erwägen*, however *abwiegen* also exists … So we’re almost back to the context argument.

Comment: Someone give me a better pair that is escaping me atm and I'll replace lesen/lassen.

Comment: *erschrecken.*         _

Comment: @Wrzlprmft And what would be the other half of the pair *erschrecken* forms?

Comment: *erschrecken* itself. It can mean *to frighten* as well as *to get frightened:* »Er erschrak, als es knallte.«; »Der Knall erschrak ihn.«